# Document with a given number of pages

Tags: counters, loops

I would like to create a calligraphy practice book filled with dotted lines but with a given number of pages i.e. 16 or 32 or 64.

Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{forloop}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{loop}
\forloop{loop}{1}{\value{loop}<33}{Page Layout \newpage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can make the question a bit more focused so that we can understand what exactly you are asking for.

Comment: Maybe something like https://gist.github.com/numberknight/dd73bb60b5d40dcc9e37 just with dotted lines? To get a defined number of pages, wrap `\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}` into a loop.

Answer (score 3):

Just set the desired number of pages and the separation between lines:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\offinterlineskip
\count255=0
\loop\ifnum\count255<32 % how many pages
  \null
  \leaders\hbox to\hsize{%
    \vrule width 0pt height 1cm % distance between lines
    \dotfill
  }\vfill
  \clearpage
  \advance\count255 by 1
\repeat

\end{document}
```

### Last page

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.

`\@whilenum\c@page<32\do{\par\dotfill}` fill all pages but last page.

`\ifdim\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\baselineskip\relax>0pt` test if there is more space in page.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\@whilenum\c@page<32\do{\par\dotfill}
\loop
\par\dotfill
\ifdim\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\baselineskip\relax>0pt
\repeat 
\makeatother
\end{document}
```