Insert something only if it fits on the current page
I want to define a command (actually, an environment’s \end) which inserts something only if there is enough vertical space remaining on the current page. The goal is to fill the remaining space with some decoration (which is flexible but has a minimum height), so, in this situation, creating a new page would be absurd. How can I do that? I did not find anything useful so far.
I am using pdfLaTeX and don’t have the option to change it.

Search the site for \pagetotal and \pagegoal, there should be plenty of results.

The code from the duplicate can be simplified to \newlength{\goodguess} in the preamble and then \goodguess=\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal\relax Remaining space is: \the\goodguess in the body at the position where you want to know how much space is left.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4017/how-to-compute-the-remaining-space-on-the-current-page/4018#4018 is also highly related but the answers are a bit less clear (because it is an old question from the start of the site when answering practises were different).

Maybe even better https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/296140/ because it also shows \ifdim to actually choose what to do based on the amount of remaining space.

My question is: how to do that? A possible answer (apparently) is: use \pagegoal and \pagetotal. The questions you point to are different in that they already assume knowledge of the answer to mine. Therefore, I (and, I assume anyone else with the same problem as me) could not find them without already knowing the seeked-for answer. Several of these questions have no explicit connection to mine. But thanks, now I know the answer and I may write it myself, if no one else cares to do it.

@Marijn  This should not be closed so we can also get an answer using an l3 internal command and something like a user command \IfPageGoalTF  and avoid the pitfalls in the last link.

@yannisl there is no L3 interface to \pagegoal or \pagetotal as far as I'm aware.

@Maëlan if you write your own code: Please keep in mind that \pagegoal and \pagetotal only give reliable results if used in vertical mode, so use \par\spaceleft=\ifdim\pagegoal=\maxdimen\textheight\else\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal\relax\fi

@Skillmon  If you read the problematic one (David Carlisle's answer to Kormylo) the problem was the mixing skips and dims, so dim_set:Nn etc for internals and then create a predicate and a user command.

@yannisl the solution is much easier: Use a dim register instead of a skip.

@Skillmon  see \tex_pagegoal:D   and \tex_pagetotal:D in source3.

@Maëlan One of the objectives of duplicate closure is exactly that: provide the missing link between a desired outcome and the tools or terminology needed to implement it. Even if the questions are not exactly the same, the similarity is usually sufficient to fix the issue - maybe with one or two comments explaining how to apply the knowledge from the other questions, as I and Skillmon have done here. Feel free to add your own answer here, however the question might still be closed because the problem is essentially solved by pointing at the duplicates.

@yannisl happy macros -> no L3 interface.

@Skillmon they busy dancing:)

@Marijn another reason for not closing this question as duplicate, is that there may be other answers than using \pagegoal / \pagetotal. For instance, perhaps the same goal can be achieved with package atbegshi(?). A high-level question does not equate a technical answer.

The following defines a macro that does your check. Please note that it adds a \par to give reliable results, hence it's not free of side effects.
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\@thirdofthree[3]{#3}
\NewDocumentCommand\ifvspaceleftTF{mmm}
  {%
    \par
    \ifdim
        \ifdim\pagegoal=\maxdimen\textheight\else\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal\fi
        <
        \dimexpr#1\relax
      \expandafter\@thirdofthree
    \fi
    \@firstoftwo{#2}{#3}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\rule{10cm}{5cm}
\ifvspaceleftTF{10cm}{enough}{not enough}
\end{document}


Thanks! I noticed this does not always work as intended. Sometimes \pagegoal-\pagetotal is negative; it seems to happen when the rendered page is almost full or almost empty. Oddly enough I could not easily find documentation about these commands, so I can only assume that, in these occasions, TeX has overflown a page but is still waiting for more contents before deciding how to best break it; and it might not break it at all, because the contents is shrinkable, so it might be shrunk to fit the page. Not knowing TeX’s decision, it is hard for me to decide if a decoration can be inserted.

@Maëlan did you include the \par? That usually makes them much more reliable. To get documentation on them: You can take a look at TeXbyTopic.

Yes I did include the \par.

@Maëlan can you create an example for which it yields completely off results?

Skillmon: here it is. Compiled with pdflatex, version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26. Pay attention to tests 3 and 5. Increasing \widowpenalty makes the problem happen more often, but as can be seen, it is already there with default settings.

@Maëlan the problem is the asynchronous output routine. On the problematic spots you actually get a negative available space because the goal for the height of the page is already surpassed. If a two-step solution is fine one could build something using labels (but I won't do it, sorry, I don't got the time right now).
